# Cola circular y operación módulo

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

estoy viendo cómo funciona una estructura de datos en C++ usando una implementación de Cola circular.

Tengo por ejemplo esta estructura:

```
template <typename T> class Cola {
   public:
      explicit Cola(size_t TamaMax);
      Cola(const Cola<T>& c);
      Cola<T>& operator =(const Cola<T>& c);
      bool vacia() const;
      bool llena() const;
      T frente() const;
      void pop();
      void push(const T& x);
      ~Cola(); // destructor
   private:
      T *elementos; 
      int Lmax;
      int inicio, fin;
};
```

Donde, si me dejáis explicaros, es un vector llamado elementos el cuál almacena el tamaño del vector en Lmax y en fin almacena la posición donde se guarda el último elemento que ha entrado en la cola.

En las operaciones de dicha estructura, **se usa mucho el módulo resto** pero no consigo saber porqué lo hace, por ejemplo, os dejo cuatro métodos en las cuáles se usa.

Método vacía (comprueba si la cola está vacía)

```
template <typename T>
inline bool Cola<T>::vacia() const
{
   return ((fin + 1) % Lmax == inicio);
}
```

Método llena (comprueba si la cola está llena)

```
template <typename T>
inline bool Cola<T>::llena() const
{
   return ((fin + 2) % Lmax == inicio);
}
```

Método pop (elimina un elemento por el frente/inicio de la cola)

```
template <typename T>
inline void Cola<T>::pop()
{
   assert(!vacia());
   inicio = (inicio + 1) % Lmax;
}
```

Método push (inserta un elemento en el final de la cola)

```
template <typename T>
inline void Cola<T>::push(const T& x)
{
   assert(!llena());
   fin = (fin + 1) % Lmax;
   elementos[fin] = x;
}
```

Sé que más o menos se hace porque precisamente si al inicio y fin tanto si el vector se llena como si está vacío coinciden las posiciones y entonces si se da el caso de que inicio y fin están en la misma posición no sé si es porque está vacío el vector o no, pero no entiendo porqué usa el módulo en esas operaciones.

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Se han complicado en el método `vacía` y `llena`. Para estos casos, siempre es bueno tener un atributo en la clase en la cual guarde la cantidad actuales de elementos que tenga el *array*. De este modo, los métodos vacía y llenar se implementan de forma sencilla. Ej: `count == 0` (con esto se verifica que la cola está vacía). Otro ej: `count == Lmax` (con esto se verifica que la cola está llena). Listo, nos ahorramos el operador módulo. El operador módulo del método `pop` es para actualizar el frente de la cola (es decir, el primer elemento).

Comment: Con respecto a `push`, ese módulo sirve para obtener la posición donde vas a insertar el elemento. Si usas la técnica que mencioné anteriormente, sería de esta forma: `fin = (fin + count) % Lmax` (con esto obtenemos la siguiente posición donde colocaremos el elemento, claro, si sabemos la cantidad actual de elementos). Por cierto, el término `push` y `pop` se suele usar cuando haces un TDA de pila. Para colas, se suele usar los términos `dequeue` y `enqueue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad que tiene la función módulo es que repite valores periódicamente:

[image]

Esto nos permite que, si tenemos diez elementos en la cola circular y `fin` vale `9`:

```
elementos | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          |v0 |v1 |v2 |v3 |v4 |v5 |v6 |v7 |v8 |v9 |
                                               ^^^
                                               fin
```

Al insertar un nuevo elemento deberíamos hacerlo en `10`, pero `10 % 10` es cero, así que vamos a la primera posición:

```
elementos | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          |v10|v1 |v2 |v3 |v4 |v5 |v6 |v7 |v8 |v9 |
           ^^^
           fin
```

No se lo que es `inicio`, así que no puedo hablar de la implementación de las funciones que muestras, pero espero que la explicación te sea de ayuda.

Comment: me ayudó mucho tu explicación. Inicio es el frente de la cola, es decir, por donde se sacan o salen los elementos de la cola y el fin es digamos por donde entran los elementos a la cola. Si quieres editar tu respuesta me encantaría leerte. GRACIAS! ^^

Comment: @ProgrammerJr deberías editar tu pregunta, ya que las funciones de las que te surgen dudas usan la variable `inicio` pero esta variable no está declarada en ninguna parte de tu código.

Comment: Añadido @PaperBirdMaster gracias!